# Where to get the DOS version of "DataTalk" (for Aladin diving computers)?

Tags: gear, scuba-diving

In order to configure my Aladin diving computer, I built the interface as described [here](http://www.muenster.de/~matthias/aladin/building.htm).
The software "DataTalk" can be used to configure the diving computer. However, the Windows version (which can be downloaded [on the manufacturer's website](http://www.scubapro.com/en-GB/FRA/product-support.aspx?subject=manuals) together with "DataTrak") only works with an original "MemoMouse" – which is quite expensive for just using it once (for configuration).

The DOS version of DataTalk seems to work with the self-built interface. However, all the links I find are outdated since about 2006 or 2009.

Do you know where you can still get the DOS version?

Comment: This seems to be about outdoor software and not an outdoor activity.

Comment: Try [softwarerecs.SE].

Comment: @gerrit [did that](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/21500/15864), thx! However, I think divers who have this program are more likely to be around here.

Comment: yes there is always an issue with stuff that fit into more than one category.

Answer (score 1):

After a little digging, I found [this link on the Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/19980625095004/http://www.downco.demon.co.uk/dtrak.zip), which seems to be what you've looking for. The zip file unpacks successfully and I had no trouble installing DataTrak and DataTalk (version 1.6) under the DOSBox emulator. They both seem to run fine under emulation as well, though I don't have the requisite hardware to test the functionality. Here's a screenshot of DataTalk running under DOSBox:

[image: DataTalk]

This is a still from DataTrak's magnificent animated start-up screen:

[image: DataTrak]